# SQL Server table to be retrieved using ADO in VC++

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado

I have a table with 2 columns, PatientID and TestNo. PatientID can be same for more than 1 records but the TestNo will be always distinct. I want to know the SQL statement which can fetch me the highest value in the TestNo field among all  the records which has same PatientID
basically max(TestNo) . I want to pass the specific PatientID in the SQL statement and the query must return the highest TestNo field value among the records which has the PatientID as passed in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the max per Patient

```
SELECT  PatientID,
        MAX(TestNo)
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY PatientID
```

This will get you the max number for pation 100

```
SELECT  MAX(TestNo)
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   PatientID = 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Sir...I will impliment it and get back to you

Comment: SELECT MAX(TestNo) FROM ECGDetails WHERE PatientID='%s' GROUP BY PatientID .This is the SQL statement which is working now but i not able to retrieve the data using the RecordSet pointer using ADO in a VC++ solution